# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, android-studio, inflate-exception

I'm a beginner in android and i want to program a calculator (press [here](https://github.com/the-Nivek/Calculator.git) to see the project), but i get [this](https://github.com/the-Nivek/Calculator/blob/master/error.txt) error.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

hello Kevin you are using wrong constraint i.e widget the error tells you that it occurred in line to change your constraint layout from

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

to

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I changed this and it says [this](https://github.com/the-Nivek/Calculator/blob/master/error.png) but i added the dependency and I still get the same [error](https://github.com/the-Nivek/Calculator/blob/master/error.txt) when I run the app.

What does "MissingClass" mean?